# Setting Target Code Coverage with Karma/Istanbul

Tags: javascript, maven, karma-runner, istanbul, karma-coverage

I'm running the Karma Maven plugin with Karma-Coverage(Istanbul) for code coverage. Karma-Coverage seems to default at 80% for required (suggested?) code coverage, however I want to enforce 90% code coverage in the project. However, I can't figure out where to set this.

Is there a way to enforce a target code coverage with Karma/Istanbul?

Answer (score 2):

This is documented in the [docs file in the repo.](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-coverage/blob/master/docs/configuration.md) Look for the section on the "check" property.

> This will be used to configure minimum threshold enforcement for coverage results. If the thresholds are not met, karma will return failure. Thresholds, when specified as a positive number are taken to be the minimum percentage required. When a threshold is specified as a negative number it represents the maximum number of uncovered entities allowed.
>
> For example, `statements: 90` implies minimum statement coverage is 90%. `statements: -10` implies that no more than 10 uncovered statements are allowed.
>
> `global` applies to all files together and `each` on a per-file basis. A list of files or patterns can be excluded from enforcement via the `exclude` property. On a per-file or pattern basis, per-file thresholds can be overridden via the `overrides` property.

```
coverageReporter: {
  check: {
    global: {
      statements: 50,
      branches: 50,
      functions: 50,
      lines: 50,
      excludes: [
        'foo/bar/**/*.js'
      ]
    },
    each: {
      statements: 50,
      branches: 50,
      functions: 50,
      lines: 50,
      excludes: [
        'other/directory/**/*.js'
      ],
      overrides: {
        'baz/component/**/*.js': {
          statements: 98
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you look in the code referenced by @MarcoCI, you'll see karma is doing a fairly standard options merge, which means you don't have to recreate the whole check object. Just the values you care about. Defaults are 0.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [check](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-coverage/blob/master/docs/configuration.md#check) option as @SeanH's answer.

Comment: The watermarks property has to do with thresholds for reporter output and not about making your tests fail if thresholds are not met.